# The field of rational functions of two variables

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help with proving this very elementary theorem:
The field of rational functions of two variables above F (F is a field) is isomorphic to the field of rational functions of one variable above the field of rational functions of one variables above F.

Thank you

Comment: First, guess what the map $\varphi$ realizing the isomorphism should be. (How many elements of $F(T,S)$ do you need to define $\varphi$ on?)